# Openlayer view fit to features crop feature icon

Tags: openlayers

I have cluster with some features inside, and when clicking to cluster, I need to zoom to those features inside. I did everything like described in this post in answers [Continue zooming in when smaller clusters are tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274925/continue-zooming-in-when-smaller-clusters-are-tapped/56275817#56275817) and when clicking to cluster I receive the following view.

[image]

Here we can see that features fits the extent, but visually it is not very good: some of features(actually feature icon) are cutted off. I tried to add some padding to fit function like `map.getView().fit(extent, { padding: [20, 20, 20, 20] });`. But another problem has arised:

[image]

Not all features are zoomed in, but I want see all features opened. I also tried constrainResolution to false, but no luck.
How that can be fixed, any tips are welcomed, as I am running out of ideas.

Comment: If you have two features at exactly the same location they will always be clustered in a cluster layer.  The only workaround is to use separate cluster and unclustered layers and switch between them (using their `.setVisible()` method) - but then one feature could be hidden behind the other.

Comment: Take a look at the most recent example https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/cluster.html  Clicking on a cluster zooms in on the cluster, but that may contain many smaller clusters,  Padding is definitely a good idea if you have large icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ol/interaction/SelectCluster to springs features apart on select. It's part of ol-ext extensions.

See example: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html